# Scala for yield rerun empty List for all the Tuples

Tags: scala

I have some issue with this this simple  for yield  operation.

```
 for {
        relatedPostMd <- postMd.get.filter(_.fromID == userID)
        nextUrl <- (ch \ "paging" \ "next").asOpt[String] // string
      } yield  (nextUrl, relatedPostMd)
```

If the   result of the filter is  none (no match for the filter opration).

Then all the Tuple is empty   even though im sure that there is value in   **nextUrl** .

the complete method

```
 def getPostMD(userID: String, url: String): Future[List[(String, PostMD)]] = {


    val chunk: Future[JsValue] = Methods.getJsonValue(url)

    chunk.map(ch => {
      val postMd: Option[List[PostMD]] = (ch \ "data").asOpt[List[PostMD]]

      for {
        relatedPostMd <- postMd.get.filter(_.fromID == userID)
        nextUrl <- (ch \ "paging" \ "next").asOpt[String]
      } yield  (nextUrl, relatedPostMd)
    })

  }
```

thanks,

miki

Comment: "If the result of the filter is none (no match for the filter opration). Then all the Tuple is empty even though im sure that there is value in nextUrl ." Yes, that's how for comprehensions work. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Paul i basically want to return the result of the filter and the string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` comprehension is sugar for `flatMap`.  So, your code is basically equivalent to this:

```
postMd.get.filter(_.fromID == userID).map { relatedPostMd => 
   x
}
```

Obviously, when list, returned by `filter` is empty, the `.map` produces an empty list as a result. If you want some special handling for that case, you first of all need to decide what you want the second element of the tuple to be (and how many tuples you want to return) when there are no matches. Then you could do something like this:

```
postMd.get.filter(_.fromID == userID) match {
   case Nil => List(whateverYourSentinelValueIs)
   case x => x
}.map { relatedPostMd => 
    ((ch \ "paging" \ "next"), relatedPostMd)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this:

```
val postMd: Option[List[Int]] = ???
val next: Option[String] = ???

val defaultPostMd = -1
val defaultNext = ""
val nextVals = next.toList

val res = postMd
  .getOrElse(Nil)
  .filter(_ % 2 == 1) // << your filter
  .zipAll(nextVals, defaultPostMd, nextVals.lift(0).getOrElse(defaultNext))
```

1)

```
val postMd: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val next: Option[String] = Some("next")

List((1,next), (3,next), (5,next))
```

2)

```
val postMd: Option[List[Int]] = None
val next: Option[String] = Some("next")

List((-1,next))
```

3)

```
val postMd: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val next: Option[String] = None

List((1,), (3,), (5,))
```

4)

```
val postMd: Option[List[Int]] = None
val next: Option[String] = None

List()
```